# prisma2 migrate Error: There are more migrations in the database than locally

Tags: prisma, nexus-prisma, prisma2

I am building backend app using prisma2 + typescript + nexus + graphql-yoga. I have defined my schema now while trying to save migrate by running command:

```
prisma2 migrate save --name "init" --experimental
```

Getting the following error.

> Error: There are more migrations in the database than locally. This
> must not happen. Local migration ids: . Remote migration ids:
> 20200312230215-init, 20200312232858-init2

Answer (score 9):

This is due to a mismatch between the migrations that were executed against the database and the migrations in your `prisma/migrations` folder.

This happens under the following circumstances:

1. Create a migration with `prisma2 migrate save --name “init” --experimental`
2. Execute the migration with `prisma2 migrate up --experimental`
3. Delete the migration files in your `prisma/migrations` folder
4. Try to run `prisma2 migrate save --name “new-migration” --experimental`

At step 4 you will see that error.

Prisma keeps track of the executed migrations in the database in a table called `_Migration`.

To solve the problem try to delete the `_Migration` table in the database. With SQLite you can do it as follows:

```
sqlite3 prisma/dev.db "delete from _Migration"
```

If that doens't work, you need to recreate the database. If you’re using sqlite, delete the `prisma/dev.db` file (you will lose all data in the database).

To prevent this in the future, make sure that you start with a clean database and if you reuse the same database avoid deleting migration files (in `prisma/migrations` after they’ve been executed.

Comment: This can also happen if you switch between different branches that differ in the migrations executed, but use the same database.

Comment: There is also no _Migration table for a postgres datasource.

Comment: The solution for me was to delete the migrations folder and remove the database in postgres.

Answer (score -1):

this happens when there are a conflict with the schema.Prisma file and the database which you have used migration you have used the old database and there is a table witch his name _Migration
how to solve
so please try to drop him by user interface or command line name_database delete from _Migration   and try to exec `yarn prisma migrate save --experimental` or `prisma2 migrate save --name “new-migration” --experimental`
it should be work